# i want to display my state with .map()

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

i have a state like this :

[image]

i want to display it with .map() in my render like this :

```
{this.state.markers.map((marker, key) => (
     <Marker
         key={key}
         coordinate={this.state.markers[marker].coordinate}
         title={this.state.markers[marker].title}
         description={this.state.markers[marker].address}
         image={require('../images/community.png')}
      />
 ))}
```

but with every test, i have this response:

**`this.state.markers.map is not a function`**

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your **ScreenShot**, `this.state.markers` is not an `array` it is an `Object`, *therefore you can't map it as is*.

In order to map it you need to use [`Object.keys`](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=object.keys&oq=object.keys&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i61l3.2320j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

The resulting code will become

```
{Object.keys(this.state.markers).map((marker, key) => (
    <Marker
        key={key}
        coordinate={this.state.markers[marker].coordinate}
        title={this.state.markers[marker].title}
        description={this.state.markers[marker].address}
        image={require('../images/community.png')}
    />
))}
```

Comment: Of course, thank you. How did I not think of that? ^^